# asp.net forms with ssl - access to log file denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, ssl

Still getting my feet wet on asp.net concepts. I have written a fairly simple e-commerce site on our company server (in C#), nothing elaborate, that only creates an email of the items that the buyer wants to order, which is sent to our order processing dept. Because the email also contains the buyer's credit card information, the page is SSL.

I had written a part of the code to log certain events in a text file, and it worked well in development, but when deployed to the SSL page, the page crashes because access to the text file is denied.

Our IT manager tells me this creates a vulnerability for our website, which is something that I don't understand but I accept because he knows a whole lot more about that kind of stuff than I do.

My question is, is there an alternative way to log events that doesn't compromise security?

It's not an essential thing, so it can be left off, but I just want to understand it a little better, at least.

Thanks!

Comment: `but when deployed to the SSL page, the page crashes because access to the text file is denied.` -> I do not understand what is happening here, but this is what you need to solve.

Comment: i don't think the SSL has anything to do with it, I believe this is all about the priv's related to the process account and it not allowing file system writes to the directory it's attempting.

Comment: How about if I point the logging path to a different directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

log to the DB, if DB writing to DB fails then log to EventViewer, the process that is running the w3wp process should be given creds to do this.  This is not any security policy violation, the containing process owner should be given adequate privs to log.

However, allowing the process to delete/create file system objects outside of it's normal behavior could be seen as a security policy violation.

Comment: To clarify your comment about it not being a security issue, are you saying that our IT guy is mistaken?

Comment: i'm saying that giving a process adequate priv's is not a security policy violation.

Comment: however allowing the process to write to "any" file and/or create any file is a security policy violation.  That is why writing to the DB for logging is a simple and perfectly acceptable method.  However "if" the write to the DB fails logging to the event log as a last measure is ok as well.

Comment: I think I have no choice but to defer to our IT guy. If he prefers not to allow writes to the directory, I have to assume he has good reasons.

Comment: then log in the DB.  BTW, writing to the event log is not the same as writing to a file in a directory.  Event viewer entries are a a standard MS mechanism.

Comment: This issue is still outstanding for me because I have had to move to a new problem. Once I get that solved I'll try the EventViewer approach, and then come back to report how it went. Thanks, everyone.